# Export 300dpi tiff of plotly plot in R

Tags: r, export, plotly

Is there a way to export a 300dpi tiff of a plotly plot? 
I have a sunburst chart I'm trying to export but I can't find a good way to get the resolution I need.

Comment: does `ggsave` work with plotly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to install orca. Please find the installation instructions [here](https://github.com/plotly/orca#installation).

Once it is installed you can use plotly's `orca()` function. The [plotly book](https://plotly-r.com/exporting-static-images.html#sizing-exports) gives the following information regarding exports specified in inches (DPI):

> It’s worth noting that the height and width of a static image must be
>   specified in pixels, which is intuitive for most file formats (png,
>   jpeg, svg, etc) but when exporting to pdf, you might want to specify
>   the size in inches. If you multiply the DPI of your machine’s display
>   by the number of inches you want, you’ll get the desired result.

Accordingly for 300 DPI you will need something like:

```
orca(plot_ly(), width = 8 * 300, height = 11 * 300)
```

Also, you might want to see [this](https://plotly.com/r/static-image-export/) related article.

Comment: When output is scaled that way then the font doesn't scale with it. Is there a way to maintain the font scaling too?